# Resource leak: 'in' is not closed at this location

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just want someone to review my code and suggestion to improve this as a well-written java code.
What I am doing is getting a user input using Scanner, until user input a Number between 0-10.

```
int Ai = getInput("i", "A");
int Aj = getInput("j", "A");
int Bi = getInput("i", "B");
int Bj = getInput("j", "B");

private static int getInput(String axis, String point) {
    int coordinate = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    while(!valid){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter "+ axis +" for " + point +" > ");

        if (in.hasNextInt()){
            coordinate = in.nextInt();
            if (coordinate >= 0 && coordinate <10){
                valid = true;
                return coordinate;
            }
        }
    }
    return coordinate; 
}
```

But I am getting a warning "Resource leak: 'in' is not closed at this location" in line 11 (return coordinate;) Please can someone explain me this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to instantiate `Scanner` object `in` every time the loop runs. So place the `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` above `while` loop.

You don't need `return` inside `if` block. Because `valid = true` inside `if` block which evaluates to `false` inside `while` condition which breaks out of loop.

Use this code instead:

```
private static int getInput(String axis, String point) {

int coordinate = 0;
boolean valid = false;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!valid)
{
    if (in.hasNextInt()){
        coordinate = in.nextInt();
        if (coordinate >= 0 && coordinate <10){
        valid = true;
        }
    }
}
in.close();
return coordinate;
}
```

---

Whenever you open external resources(I/O) in your code in any language( most of them), you have to close that external resource.

Always you have to close the instances of classes that deal with I/O after you are finished with them.

Here the external resource is `System.in`, you have opened it to take the input but after your work you didn't close that resource. That is why it is asking you to close it.

If you close the scanner `in.close()` you can't use `in` to get input next time unless you open it again by instantiating it.

Add the `in.close()` above both the `return` statements and there should be no error.

---

**Edit:**

The problem is we are closing `Scanner` in the `getinput()` which is also closing `System.in` as said by "Henry" in the comments.

So declare it as `static` and close the `Scanner` at the end of the `main()`.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Declared as Static
    private static int getInput(String axis, String point) {

        int coordinate = 0;
        boolean valid = false;

        while(!valid)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter "+ axis +" for " + point +" > ");
            if (in.hasNextInt()){
                coordinate = in.nextInt();
                if (coordinate >= 0 && coordinate <10){

                valid = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return coordinate;
        }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    int Ai = getInput("i", "A");
    int Aj = getInput("j", "A"); 
    int Bi = getInput("i", "B");
    int Bj = getInput("j", "B");
    in.close(); // close the scanner when your program is about to end
}
}
```

Comment: closing the scanner would also close the underlying `System.in` which is in many cases not a good idea.

Comment: @SkrewEverything Thanks for your nice explanation. I've tried adding in.close() above the return statement. Then typed a valid number(0-10). it became to an infinity loop.

Comment: @Henry Then is it a good idea to open the scanner in `main()` and pass the input to method as a parameter and close the scanner at the end of the `main()`?

Comment: I think this would be better.

Comment: @xyzabc Check the answer, I have edited it with code and tips. The code works fine for me for input `0-9`.

Comment: @SkrewEverything  Nope :( plz can u re-run your code by adding `System.out.println("Enter "+ axis +" for " + point +" > ");` line above `hasNext()` line. _int Ai = getInput("i", "A");
     int Aj = getInput("j", "A");
     int Bi = getInput("i", "B");
     int Bj = getInput("j", "B");_

Comment: @SkrewEverything wooh! thumbs up buddy :) that's what i wanted. Thank you soooooooooooooooooo much. :*

Answer (score -1):

when dealing with multiple inputs in a single line

you should use the append the following lines to your code

```
String[] in= lines.trim().split("\\s+");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
a[i] = Integer.parseInt(in[i]);
}
```

you might not know if a user inputs data in this order the program [earlier] won't be able to parse it causing the function to fail to act properly.